$A$, $B$, $C$ are angles of a triangle if and only if $\cos^2A+\cos^2B+\cos^2C+2\cos A\cos B\cos C=1$
Wikipedia page Triangle - Angles

So we can have, for example, angles $\left\{\frac{\pi }{3},\frac{\pi }{4},\frac{5 \pi }{12}\right\}$ which sum up to $\pi$.
But then also $\left\{\frac{\pi }{3},\frac{\pi }{4},\frac{11 \pi }{12}\right\}$ which sum up to $\frac{3 \pi }{2}$. So such triangle can not exist but the angles still satisfy the equation.
So shouldn't the sentence be if a triangle exists then it must satisfy the equation instead of if and only if statement?
Or am I missing something?
Additional question. Does the equation have any name? Like we have Law of cosines, for example.
Also the version of page from 22 August 2024 was (still not correct to me):


yeah the if and only if statement is wrong. Usually, one can assume some additional conditions on the angles to make it equivalent i.e., this is true for acute triangle.

@dezdichado I think you are right and from this perspective I think the sentence before the highlighted one should be each of them between 0 and 90 instead of each of them between 0 and 180. Maybe that is what the contributor to Wikipedia intended but made an error.

You are right. The “only if” part is correct, but the statement in Wikipedia is false. As another example, take $\alpha=\frac14\pi$, $\beta=\frac34\pi$, and $\gamma=\frac12\pi$. Then the trigonometric formula holds, but these cannot be the angles of a triangle.
